# Print an UTF8-encoded smiley

Tags: utf-8, python-3.7, discord.py, decoding

I am writing an ReactionRoles-Discord-Bot in Python (discord.py).
This Bot saves the ReactionRoles-Smileys as UFT8-Encoded.

The type of the encoded is bytes but it's converted to str to save it.
The string looks something like `"b'\\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x82'"`.
I am using `EMOJI_ENCODED = str(EMOJI.encode('utf8'))` to encode it, but `bytes(EMOJI_ENCODED).decode('utf8')` isn't working.

Do you know how to decode it or how to save it in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `str()` is a Unicode string.  `EMOJI` is a Unicode string.  `str(EMOJI.encode('utf8'))` just makes a mangled Unicode string.

The purpose of encoding is to make a byte string that can be saved to a file/database/socket.  Simply do `b = EMOJI.encode()` (default is UTF-8) to get a byte string and `s = b.decode()` to get the Unicode string back.

Comment: This doesn't work.

I am saving the reactionroles into a json file.
When I want to dump the dict, this happens:
```{
    "RRs": {
        "6124083146": {
            "channel_id": "630000986974453770",
            "message_id": "696216630799106089",
            "role_ids": [
                "629719095595630592"
            ],
            "emoji_utf8": ```


It cancels the saving. 

How can I do this?

Comment: @RD4 Edit your question to clarify what you are doing and why it doesn’t work.  Make a [mcve]. FYI JSON can handle Unicode strings so no need to encode.

Comment: I worked it out now:  
I don't have to encode it in order to save the emoji